# Getting xml doc subnodes using xpath with multiple attribute values

Tags: c#, xml

Given an xml with the following structure

```
<Commodity name="coffee" title="Coffee" value="7">
  <Specs>
     ..elements removed
  </Specs>
  <ContractMonths lasttradedaterule="Eight business days prior to the last business day of the delivery month"
            firstnoticedaterule="Seven business days prior to first business day of delivery month">
     ..elements removed
  </ContractMonths>
 <Options tf="true">
   <OptionMonths delimeter="comma"
             expirationdaterule="Second Friday of the calendar month preceding such regular or serial
                option month; provided, however, that for each option, there will be a minimum of four
                trading days between the last trading day of the expiring option and the first notice
                day of the expiring future">
    <Year value="2015">
      ..elements removed
    </Year>
    <Year value="2016">
      ..elements removed
    </Year>
    <Year value="2017">
     ..elements removed
    </Year>
    <Year value="2018">
      <Jan expiration="" associatedcontract="Mar" />
      <Feb expiration="" associatedcontract="Mar" />
      <Mar expiration="02/12/18" associatedcontract="Mar" />
      <Apr expiration="" associatedcontract="May" />
      <May expiration="04/08/18" associatedcontract="May" />
      <Jun expiration="05/11/18" associatedcontract="Jul" />
      <Jul expiration="06/08/18" associatedcontract="Jul" />
      <Aug expiration="07/13/18" associatedcontract="Sep" />
      <Sep expiration="08/10/18" associatedcontract="Sep" />
      <Oct expiration="" associatedcontract="Dec" />
      <Nov expiration="" associatedcontract="Dec" />
      <Dec expiration="11/09/18" associatedcontract="Dec" />
    </Year>
  <Year value="2019">
   ..elements removed
  </Year>     
</OptionMonths>
```

There are over 25 Commodity elements

I can retrieve the commodity element I want like so, using the name attribute value

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load(@"https://batlgroupimages.blob.core.windows.net/accessibleimages/CommodityData.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> elem =
            doc.Descendants("Commodity").Where(el =>
            {
                var xAttribute = el.Attribute("name");
                return xAttribute != null && xAttribute.Value == commodity;
            });
```

I need to drill down further to get a nodelist of the year elements given the value attribute of the Year element equals whatever year I pass in.

I am trying to do it in one statement

```
var dates = elem.Descendants("Options/@tf='true'/OptionMonths/Year/@value='2015'");
```

It reads correctly ( to me anyway) get the descendants where Options has the tf value of true, get the OptionMonths/Years where year value = 2015

I can do it in shorter steps but Im certain there is a quicker solution.

**Update**
Based on jdweng's answer I came up with the following which returns the year passed in to the method

```
var year = elem.Descendants("Options")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("tf")?.Value == "true").Descendants("Year")
            .Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("value") == yearvalue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string xAttribute = "coffee";
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>> dict = doc.Descendants("Commodity").Where(el => xAttribute == (string)el.Attribute("name"))
                .Select(x => x.Descendants("Year")
                .GroupBy(s => (int)s.Attribute("value"), t => t.Elements()
                    .GroupBy(u => u.Name.LocalName, v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>((string)v.Attribute("expiration"), (string)v.Attribute("associatedcontract")))
                        .ToDictionary(u => u.Key, v => v.FirstOrDefault()))
                        .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, t => t.FirstOrDefault())).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @jdweng...I see where you are going, a bit complicated for what I am trying to accomplish. Was trying to use xPath. Need to be able to cull the years by finding the attribute "value" of the Year being equal to what is passed in. I tried a few different ways using the base of your linq but no success

Comment: @jdweng...See op for my solution, your answer did help somewhat. Isn't my solution more concise and do the same thing?

Comment: Your solution is returning the entire xml Element, my solution is extraction the values from the element.  So I end up with an object : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>>  The int is the year, the key of 2nd dictionary is the month, and the keyvaluepair is the expiration & associatedcontract attributes.

Comment: @jdweng...ok that actually works better for me but how to limit the result to just the year passed in? So the result is just a dictionary where the key is the month, and the dictionary of string string has the expiration and another attribute?

Comment: You only want one year?  Then year doesn't have to be part of results.